# Laravel paginate items in multiple categories

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, pagination

I have 2 tables, products and categories. Products belong to different categories, and categories are formed in tree structure that allows for parent category and child category relationship. So given a specific category, how should I write query to get paginated products that belong to this category and all its child categories?

I forgot to mention that in my settings, products and categories are many to many relationship, there is a pivoting table named product_catrgory.

Comment: You need `whereHas` that checks for related categories with `whereIn('id', $ids)`, and those `$ids` are recursively fetched. I would think of better setup for this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get you, are you referring better setup as in the relationship setup? Meaning that each product should belong to one and only one category? I'm no expert at ecommerce system, what are the general setup for this relationship?

Comment: I mean the tree structure of the categories. Read about other types of schema for self referencing table relationships.

Answer (score 1):

```php
$ids = $category->children()->lists('id');

$ids[] = $category->id;

$products = Product::whereIn('category_id', $ids)->paginate(20);
```

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek - Not just shorter but way more efficient. There's no need in this case to load all the children models.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is other better method but you could do it this way:

```
$ids = [];

$ids[] = $category->id;

foreach ($category->children as $child) {
  $ids[] = $child->id;
}

$products = Product::whereIn('cat_id', $ids)->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simplest way to do this is to first get category id and its all child category id recursively. And query the database using whereIn(array of category id) to get all the products.  I do not think you can do it in one single query.